# Django vs Play framework in terms of performance

Tags: django, playframework, django-forms, playframework-2.0, django-admin

Django uses a threaded architecture unlike Play framework which uses Evented architecture. 
I wanted to compare Django with Play framework. Which one performs better if we deploy the services written in Django and Play on the hardware with same configuration, also given that business logic for the service has been written effeciently in both the frameworks? Which framework has the potential to scale to 1000+ concurrent requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads and events are not a dichotomy, Play gives you threads and an event loop.

This question is too broad, it really depends on what you're trying to implement - in many many use cases the web framework is not the bottleneck, it's the database.  But if you insist on getting on a comparison that completely ignores whatever your specific use case is, then here's a comparison:

http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9&hw=peak&test=json&f=2hwco-0-0-0

Comment: Thanks for the details. How is django architecture different from Play framework?